# Adding headers to HTTP response when not returning a Response object in JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jax-rs, cxf

I am creating a REST service using CXF 3.1.4 and JAX-RS. I have created an interface that is shared between client and server:

```java
public interface SubscriptionsService {

    @POST
    @Path("/subscriptions")
    SubscriptionResponse create(SubscriptionRequest request);
}

public class SubscriptionResponse {
    private String location;
}
```

The client is created using `JAXRSClientFactoryBean` and the server is created using `JAXRSServerFactoryBean`.

The `create()` method defined above should return a `Location` header but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to return a `SubscriptionResponse` object instead of a [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) object, you can inject the [`HttpServletResponse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) in your JAX-RS enpoint class using the [`Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation and set the `201` status code and the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header:

```java
@Context 
HttpServletResponse response;

@POST
@Path("/subscriptions")
public SubscriptionResponse create(SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequest) {
    
    // Persist your subscripion to database

    SubscriptionResponse subscriptionResponse = ...
    URI createdUri = ...
    
    // Set HTTP code to "201 Created" and set the Location header
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
    response.setHeader("Location", createdUri.toString());
     
    return subscriptionResponse;
}
```

---

When returning a [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) object, you can and use the [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) API to add the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header, as following:

```java
@POST
@Path("/subscriptions")
public Response create(SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequest) {

    // Persist your subscripion to database
    
    URI createdUri = ...
    return Response.created(createdUri).build();
}
```

For more details have a look at the [`Response.created(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#created-java.net.URI-) method documentation.